# InvalidArgument: Webhook views require an associated state with the webhook

Tags: python, discord, webhooks, nextcord

I'm trying to get a webhook setup with python and nextcord. I would like the embedded messaged thats passed to the discord to include buttons that have callbacks when clicked. Not the most experienced with python. Been looking at documentation for days and no luck.

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands
from nextcord import File, ButtonStyle, Embed, Member
from nextcord.ui import Button, View
from nextcord import Webhook, TextChannel


async def send_to_webhook(id, token):
    embed = Embed(color=0x000ff)
    embed.add_field(name="Test", value="Test", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Upvotes", value="0", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Downvotes", value="0", inline=True)

    count = 0
    count1 = 0
    button = Button(label="Upvote", style=ButtonStyle.green, emoji="")
    button1 = Button(label="Downvotes", style=ButtonStyle.red, emoji="")
    button2 = Button(label="Test", url='http://www.google.com', style=ButtonStyle.url)


    async def button_callback(interaction):
        nonlocal count
        count += 1
        await interaction.message.edit(embed=embed.set_field_at(index=1, name="Upvotes", value=count))

    button.callback = button_callback

    async def button_callback(interaction):
        nonlocal count1
        count1 += 1
        await interaction.message.edit(embed=embed.set_field_at(index=2, name="Downvotes", value=count1))

    button1.callback = button_callback

    view = View()
    view.add_item(button)
    view.add_item(button1)
    view.add_item(button2)

    # Create a new HTTP session and use it to create webhook object
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        webhook = Webhook.partial(id, token, session=session)
        await webhook.send(embed=embed, view=view)

asyncio.run(send_to_webhook("ID", "TOKEN"))
```

I keep getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michael\PycharmProjects\AlphaWave\button-test2.py", line 48, in <module>
    asyncio.run(send_to_webhook("952777439615004763", "VJlnbm64i7oBljBJcSFkcDvKziC8UZplGkBjlLlmMhxvlz2f_J28lUoznp1kAZXQEjye"))
  File "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Michael\PycharmProjects\AlphaWave\button-test2.py", line 46, in send_to_webhook
    await webhook.send(embed=embed, view=view)
  File "C:\Users\Michael\PycharmProjects\AlphaWave\venv\lib\site-packages\nextcord\webhook\async_.py", line 1417, in send
    raise InvalidArgument('Webhook views require an associated state with the webhook')
nextcord.errors.InvalidArgument: Webhook views require an associated state with the webhook
```

Comment: doc for [send( view )](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=webhook#nextcord.Webhook.send): `You can only send a view if this webhook is not partial and has state attached. A webhook has state attached if the webhook is managed by the library.`

Comment: @furas I'm fresh to python and I'm not entirely sure what that means

Comment: I didn't search details but this doc shows one think: you can't use `partial()`. I still don't know how to add `state` to `webhook`. It would need to dig in source code to see how `"the library"` uses it.

Comment: @w00di In case my original answer did not help, see my updated answer as I have added more details

Answer (score 1):

In order to send components, it must be an application-owned webhook. (See [Discord docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook)).

In nextcord, you will also need the application's connection state as part of the Webhook, so you will need a Webhook object and not a PartialWebhook.

Example:

```py
# create a new webhook
webhook = await channel.create_webhook(name="Test")

# send a message to the webhook
await webhook.send("Hello World!", view=MyView())
```

Of course, you don't have to create a new webhook each time. You can have the bot create it once and fetch it later with `await client.fetch_webhook(id)` or `await channel.webhooks()`.